# Android Database Synchronisation with Server using Thread

Tags: android, sqlite, service, intentservice

I want to sync database from Server to Android (One way) in background on BOOT_COMPLETED.

- My service is of long duration
- I want to get `JSON` from server
- Access local sqlite db.
- download image from url i got from JSON

Should I use Service or `Service` with `Thread` or `IntentService`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service.  An IntentService is meant for when you're sending down multiple requests that you want to be handled by the service, which is meant to run to completion then exit.  Here we want to start up once and then run.  That's a better fit for Service.

Comment: if I am implementing a long task, should i implement Thread inside Service

Comment: Yes.  Because the Service shares the same main thread as Activities use.  An AsyncTask may also be appropriate, depending on the use case.